# Sas to snowpark

Tags: sas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on converting SAS code to Snowflake and I got a scenario to implement "PROC TRANSPOSE" functionality in Snowflake. Below is the same table data I have in snowflake and I need to transpose rows into columns and columns into rows at a time.

0

Sample Input Data:

1

Sample Output Data:

2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your examples consist of single numbers (integers), not tables. Could you please [edit] the post with a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Without a more complete understanding of the input data and expected output it is difficult to give a definite answer. However, with Snowpark you would want to use pandas DataFrame.transpose

```py
>>> df
       TYPE                                       NAME
0     AA_ID                     ["AA_1","AA_2","AA_3"]
1     QQ_ID              ["QQ_A","QQ_B","QQ_C","QQ_D"]
2     ZZ_ID                     ["ZZ_1","ZZ_2","ZZ_3"]
>>> df2 = df.transpose()
>>> df2
>>> df2
                           0                              1                       2
TYPE                   AA_ID                          QQ_ID                   ZZ_ID
NAME  ["AA_1","AA_2","AA_3"]  ["QQ_A","QQ_B","QQ_C","QQ_D"]  ["ZZ_1","ZZ_2","ZZ_3"]
```

Comment: if the data is already in a Snowflake table, then using a pandas function requires all the data to be moved into the dataframe.  Leveraging a native Snowpark function against a Snowpark dataframe would be a lot more efficient.  Wouldn't `df.unpivot` or `df.pivot` be more efficient to use?